# How can I get this imported MouseMotionListener to work again?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, mousemotionlistener

I made a JPanel with a mouse listener, a mouse motion listener and a scroll listener. And I have a JFrame that switches between JPanels like so:

```
    //tile is a JPanel
    //"this" is a JFrame

            tile.removeAll();
            tile=tree.getCurrentNode().getContent().panel;
            this.add(tile);
            this.revalidate();
            tile.requestFocus();
```

Now when I switch out the old JPanel for the one with mouse listeners some weird things start to happen. The mouse listener and the scroll listener still work but the mouse motion listener doesn't get called anymore. I even get a nullpointer exception when I try getMousePosition() from within the JPanel.

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: I'll see what I can do, the current project is far too big to get into.

Comment: Can you please provide code for adding listeners and using them?

Comment: I figured out what my problem was, the mousemotionlistener was actually working but getMousePosition() wasn't working, so I fixed it like this:


`    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) 
 {
  mousePosition=new Point(
    (int)(MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().getX() - this.getLocationOnScreen().x) ,
    (int)(MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().getY() - this.getLocationOnScreen().y)
    );`

Comment: Use a [`CardLayout`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html) as shown in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5786005/418556).